# Fill external form with cURL

Tags: php, forms, post, curl

I'm trying to fill and submit an external form using cURL, but actually I can't fill the field and I would understand why.

How can I see the filled form, immediately after the form submission?

I have the following code:

```
    <?php

         //create array of data to be posted
           $post_data['fname'] = 'Mario';
           $post_data['lname'] = 'Rossi';
           $post_data['email'] = 'mario@rossi.it';
           $post_data['memberid'] = '1010101010';
           $post_data['mobile'] = '3456789';


         //traverse array and prepare data for posting (key1=value1)

           foreach ( $post_data as $key => $value) {
                   $post_items[] = $key . '=' . $value;
           }

           //create the final string to be posted using implode()

           $post_string = implode ('&', $post_items);

           //create cURL connection
           $curl_connection = 
                   curl_init('http://dennehys.ie/mobile/douglas/formview.php?qstr=dHlwbz0mZGF5PVR1ZXNkYXkmZGF5ZGF0ZT0yMDE2LTAxLTI2JnJuZD0mY2xhc3NzaGVkdWxlPTQ5Mw==');

          //set options
          curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
          curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
          "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
          curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
          curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
          curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

          //set data to be posted
          curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);

          //perform our request
          $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
          print_r($post_data);
          echo $result;

          //show information regarding the request

          print_r(curl_getinfo($curl_connection));
          echo curl_errno($curl_connection) . '-' . 
            curl_error($curl_connection);

         //close the connection
          curl_close($curl_connection);

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page you are posting to, the form has the following line:

```
<form action="formresponse.php" method="post" data-ajax="false" name="book">
```

This implies that you are posting data to the *wrong* page, as all the posted data from that form goes to `formresponse.php`. It's likely that the page you're sending to doesn't do anything with the data you're posting.

Try changing this line:

```
curl_init('http://dennehys.ie/mobile/douglas/formview.php?qstr=dHlwbz0mZGF5PVR1ZXNkYXkmZGF5ZGF0ZT0yMDE2LTAxLTI2JnJuZD0mY2xhc3NzaGVkdWxlPTQ5Mw==');
```

to:

```
curl_init('http://dennehys.ie/mobile/douglas/formresponse.php');
```

Comment: I tried to change the line that you told me, but the page show me the following response: Please provide a valid email. I tried to paste the url: 'http://dennehys.ie/mobile/douglas/formresponse.php' in the browser but the response is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line and I fixed my code, because there were four hidden input type, now the code looks working but I'm not really sure.

The hidden inputs type are:

'typo' an empty field (I think that field is empty)

'day' = 'wednesday'; (the day when you want book the class)

'clsdl' = '485'; (class ID)

'daydate' = '2016-01-27'; (date of the class)

When I send the request the code answers me with a success message.

Now I can't understand how I can send a request to book a class at specific time.

What I mean is, Is possibile to have two classes of the same sport in the same day and I want to specify the class that I want book.

I tried to read the source code of the page but I can't understand how can I do that.